The sum 4 product of binomial coefficients
I'm interested in the following sum: $\sum_{m=1}^{t}\binom{m+i-2}{i-1}\binom{t-m+n-i}{n-i}\binom{m+j-2}{j-1}\binom{t-m+n-j}{n-j}$
This sum arises when calculating the order polynomial for a type of 2-chain. The thing to notice is that $\sum_{m=1}^{t}\binom{m+i-2}{i-1}\binom{t-m+n-i}{n-i} = \binom{t+n-1}{n}$ which is just the Chu-Vandermonde identity. But I don't think I can use convolution again to obtain the anything meaningful in the original expression.
Any thoughts are appreciated.
Edit 1: I just read about WZ method. And it seems to me that the summand is likely proper-hypergeometric at this point. Unluckily I don't have access to either Mathematica or Maple. If someone can check this using WZ method it would be great.

@CalvinLin The first one is correct. $\binom{n}{r} = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient Wiki called my expression "another form of Chu-Vandermonde identity".

I tried to do the WZ method on this summation, and it appears there is no closed form. I used the program Maxima to run Zeilberger’s algorithm.

I don't know how helpful it will be, but here is an observation. Let $$A=\left[\binom{m+i-2}{i-1}\binom{t-m+n-i}{n-i}\right]$$ be an $n\times t$ matrix with $1\le i\le n$ (rows), $1\le m\le t$ (columns). Then the sum in the question is $(AA^T)_{ij}$.
